# Getting Elapsed Time in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, elapsedtime

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/2py6b/)

I am making a social network and when you post something, I want to show the time. I have the current code to display the time (this isn't only the time, it's also validating and posting the text):

```
$('#b').click(function () {
    var v = $('#type').val();
    var u = $('#input').val();
    if (v !== "" && u !== ""){
        var time = new Date();
        var currentime = Date.now();
        var x = currentime - time;
        $("ul").prepend("<li>" + v + "<br />Posted by " + u + " " + x +" minutes ago  </li>");
        $('#type, #input').css('border','');
    }
    else if (v == "" && u == "") {
        $('#type, #input').css('border','1px solid red');
    }
    else if (v == "") {
        $('#type').css('border','1px solid red');
        $('#input').css('border','');
    }
    else {
        $('#input').css('border','1px solid red');
        $('#type').css('border','');
    }
});
```

When the time posts, it says 0 minutes ago (like I told it to), but after any amount of time, it still says 0.

Comment: Do you ever update the time indicator?

Comment: @n.st What do you mean? Do you mean using the jQuery `$().now()` method?

Comment: You will probably need to use `setInterval(...)` to update the time.

Comment: @Robb Can you please provide an answer or some sample code? I am not very familiar with `setInterval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2py6b/3/)

Basically you set up a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) which governs ho frequently you update your time attribute. I used a `span` with a class `.time` to so you could theoretically update anything with time.

I would go further and hash your posts so you can easily retrieve each posts original time.

EDIT: added a new fiddle.

Comment: Posted by 1385863066491 minutes ago ?

Comment: It shows me a long number. How would I convert this to minutes?

Comment: It's just returning the milliseconds from epoch. Default behavior. You can get the seconds or minutes.

Comment: @JJP google is your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @Robb skips from 0 min to 7 min? I don't think this is working yet

Comment: @JJP ok it seems your initial time compare was strange. I'm storing the posted time a bit better now with the newest fiddle (link updated)

Comment: @Robb I found a bug. If one person posts something, then a minute later they post something else, both of the posts turn to zero min

Comment: You'll have to tweak the code to make sure you're updating the correct things, I used a span with a class so you'll have to make a more specific selector. Good luck!