# Different Selector with jQuery Prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2py6b/3/)

I am making a social network, and I'm displaying the time elapsed in the posts. The problem is, when you post, then post again minutes later, both of the posts turn to zero. The reason for this is because in my last question, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302008/getting-elapsed-time-in-js), the solution to display elapsed time was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302260/2499019). This solution has a span in the posts with a class. The class holds the time. But when there are two of the same class, both of them turn to zero.

HTML:

```
<textarea id='type'></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<input id='input'>
<br />
<br />
<button id='b'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
</button>
<ul id='ul'></ul>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
var postedTime;
$('#b').click(function () {
    var v = $('#type').val();
    var u = $('#input').val();
    if (v !== "" && u !== "") {
        var time = new Date();
        var currentime = Date.now();
        var x = currentime - time;
        postedTime = currentime;
        $("ul").prepend("<li>" + v + "<br />Posted by " + u + " <span class='time'>" + x + "</span> minutes ago  </li>");
        window.setInterval( function () {
          var newTime = new Date(new Date() - postedTime);
          $(".time").html(newTime.getMinutes());            
        }, 1000);
      $('#type, #input').css('border', '');
    } else if (v == "" && u == "") {
      $('#type, #input').css('border', '1px solid red');
    } else if (v == "") {
      $('#type').css('border', '1px solid red');
      $('#input').css('border', '');
    } else {
      $('#input').css('border', '1px solid red');
      $('#type').css('border', '');
    }
});
```

I need a way to get a new selector with every post.

Comment: `I need a way to get a new selector with every post.` that's what classes are for. Not hard to isolate instances.

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, by my question, I obviously don't know how to isolate instances

Comment: Not even clear what your issue is....links to multiple other questions aren't the proper wayy to set up a new question...it should be aparrent reading this one what the issue is. And quite frankly, I can't tell. Don't plan to wait minutes to change things

Comment: suggest you store each `posted` time on each elemnt using `data()`...then loop through and modify individually in an `each` loop. There's an isolation right there. Currently you set all the same

Comment: I'm not quite understanding

Comment: `$(".time").html(newTime.getMinutes()); ` will set all `class=time` the same, whenever button is clicked. If you want to modify each...need to loop through each and adjust individually-per instance

Comment: what do you mean by "loop through"?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: I don't get how that method would help.

Comment: I've given you the full over view...store each posted time when it's created, then using each go through and make display adjustments.